# How to disable Chrome's "Password Leak Detection" for some sites or IP numbers

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I log in to a site, Chrome checks its online source if my password was published somewhere and warns me to change my password if there is a match.

I am doing software development on my local computer and using simple passwords for the dev environment. Chrome's Password Leak Detection keeps bugging me about my passwords everytime I log in. How can I disable this feature for some sites and/or specific IP addresses.

Note 1: I don't want to disable the Password Leak Detection feature altogether, just want to disable it for specific IP addresses.

Note 2: I know it is not a good practice to use weak passwords, even for dev environments, but I will keep using them so "you should change your passwords" is not the answer to my question.

Comment: I know of your note 2, but have you considered to change the password, to counteract that message, and simply store the password in chrome, so its filled in and you only have to press sign in? I mean, its a dev environment locally anyway, right! You could use a password manager for this too if you really don't want to use the one build into chrome.